# What is the cost of a #define?

Tags: c#, c++, c, objective-c

To define constants, what is the more common and correct way? What is the cost, in terms of compilation, linking, etc., of defining constants with #define? It is another way less expensive?

Comment: Pick a language, any language?

Comment: C# doesn't allow `#define` to be used to define constants. You can do `#define DEBUG`, but not `#define DEBUG 1`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to define any const is to write

```
const int m = 7;
const float pi = 3.1415926f;
const char x = 'F';
```

Using `#define` is a bad c++ style. It is impossible to hide `#define` in namespace scope.

Compare

```
#define pi 3.1415926
```

with

```
namespace myscope {
const float pi = 3.1415926f;
}
```

Second way is obviously better.

Comment: +1 `#define` is also poor style because it doesn't give any explicit type information to the compiler.

Comment: This accurately sums up the stylistic recommendations but doesn't answer the question.   Constants declared in the proper C++ style do have a cost that #defines do not have.

Comment: @Dan Olson: Aah but #defines also have a cost in terms of code size, as (depending on compiler smarts) you can end up introducing many literals where a single const would have done. @Espuz: neither cost is worth worrying about (unless you are doing very low-level microprocessor stuff) so go with the better style, which is `const` where possible.

Comment: @Dan Olson, what cost do C++-style constants (which happen to be constant expressions) have that `#defines` don't?

Comment: Actually, an even better way for small integers is enum{m = 7}, as you get the value compile time.

Comment: It is better but it is far from obvious without an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler itself never sees a #define.  The preprocessor expands all macros before they're passed to the compiler.  One of the side effects, though, is that the values are repeated...and two identical strings are not necessarily the exact same string.  If you say

```
#define SOME_STRING "Just an example"
```

it's perfectly legal for the compiler to add a copy of the string to the output file each time it sees the string.  A good compiler will probably eliminate duplicate literals, but that's extra work it has to do.  If you use a const instead, the compiler doesn't have to worry about that as much.

Answer (score 2):

The cost is only to the preprocessor, when #defines are resolved (ignoring the additional debugging cost of dealing with a project full of #defines for constants, of course).

Answer (score 1):

`#define` macros are processed by the pre-processor, they are not visible to the compiler. And since they are not visible to the compiler as a symbol, it is hard to debug something which involves a macro.

The preferred way of defining constants is using the const keyword along with proper type information.

```
const unsigned int ArraySize = 100;
```

Even better is

```
static const unsigned int ArraySize = 100;
```

when the constant is used only in a single file.

Answer (score 1):

#define will increase Compilation time but it will faster in execution...

generally in conditional compilation #define is used...

where const is used in general computation of numbers

Choice is depends upon your requirement...

Comment: At best the speed increase using #define will be marginal.  If the compiler optimises the consts there will be no advantage and you lose al the benefits of const.

Comment: yes... #define is handy in Conditional Compilation (in cross platform Application... ) It is the only advantage that can be considered...

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is string replacement.  So if you make mistakes in the macros, they will show up as errors later on.  Mostly incorrect types or incorrect expressions are the common ones.

For conditional compilation, pre-processor macros work best.  For other constants which are to be used in computation, `const` works good.

Answer (score 0):

CPU time isn't really the cost of using #define or macros.  The "cost" as a developer is as follows:

- If there is an error in your macro, the compiler will flag it where you referenced the macro, not where you defined it.
- You will lose type safety and scoping for your macro.
- Debugging tools will not know  the value of the macro.

These things may not burn CPU cycles, but they can burn developer cycles.

For constants, declaring `const` variables is preferable, and for little type-independent functions, inline functions and templates are preferable.